# issue with setting up Solana RPC devnet archive node

Tags: devnet

My concern is not sure with the below flags this works as a Devnet RPC archive node.

I need to know the correct way to set the devnet RPC  archive node

I checked blocks and blocks have not been updated in days.

> ```
>  curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
> ```

```
 {
   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   "id": 1,
   "method": "getBlockHeight"
 }'
```

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":264442355,"id":1}

according to the Solana block scanner above block is around 2 months old. in service startup it downloaded snapshots.

I followed Solana docs and the below guide to set the Devnet RPC archive node

[setting-up-a-solana-devnet-validator](https://github.com/agjell/sol-tutorials/blob/master/setting-up-a-solana-devnet-validator.md)

I removed --limit-ledger-size flag for the archive node.
not sure it is the way for the archive node.
this is the service file

> exec /home/ubuntu/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/solana-validator     --identity /home/ubuntu/validator-keypair.json     --known-validator dv1ZAGvdsz5hHLwWXsVnM94hWf1pjbKVau1QVkaMJ92     --known-validator dv2eQHeP4RFrJZ6UeiZWoc3XTtmtZCUKxxCApCDcRNV     --known-validator dv4ACNkpYPcE3aKmYDqZm9G5EB3J4MRoeE7WNDRBVJB     --known-validator dv3qDFk1DTF36Z62bNvrCXe9sKATA6xvVy6A798xxAS     --only-known-rpc     --full-rpc-api     --no-voting     --ledger /data/ledger     --accounts /data/accounts     --log /data/sol/solana-rpc.log     --rpc-port 8899     --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0     --private-rpc     --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020     --entrypoint entrypoint.devnet.solana.com:8001     --entrypoint entrypoint2.devnet.solana.com:8001     --entrypoint entrypoint3.devnet.solana.com:8001     --entrypoint entrypoint4.devnet.solana.com:8001     --entrypoint entrypoint5.devnet.solana.com:8001     --expected-genesis-hash EtWTRABZaYq6iMfeYKouRu166VU2xqa1wcaWoxPkrZBG     --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record